# Tableview cell did select row action based on selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I having some questions and answers

questions into one array and answers in to one array.

I want to show when user select question show the answer again select close the answer.

I write the following code but when one answer is open remains all is closed ,my logic is reverse any one plz help to me.

here I creating one global variable with selectedindex name

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DonationTableViewCell", for: indexPath)as!
    DonationTableViewCell
    cell.questioncell.text = questnArr[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row  == selectedindex
    {
        cell.answerlbl.text = answersarr[indexPath.row]
        cell.questioncell.textColor = UIColor.disSatifyclr
        cell.questionimg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Drop down top icon")

    }else{
        cell.answerlbl.text = ""
        cell.questioncell.textColor = UIColor.textmaincolor
        cell.questionimg.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Drop down")

    }
    tableviewheight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedindex = indexPath.row
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is your issue related to the row height? If so, show your `heightForRowAt`.

Comment: What is the point of the `tableviewheight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height` line in `cellForRowAt`? That should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all declare `selectedindex` as optional `IndexPath`

```
var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
```

in `didSelectRowAt` you have to perform some checks:

- If `selectedIndexPath == nil` select the row at `indexPath`
- If `selectedIndexPath != nil` and `selectedIndexPath == indexPath` deselect the row at `indexPath`
- If `selectedIndexPath != nil` and `selectedIndexPath != indexPath` deselect the row at `selectedIndexPath` and select row at `indexPath`.

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndexPath == nil {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    } else {
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath! {
           selectedIndexPath = nil
           tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        } else {
           let currentIndexPath = selectedIndexPath!
           selectedIndexPath = indexPath
           tableView.reloadRows(at: [currentIndexPath, indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

In `cellForRowAt` check

```
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath
```